# Problems with the GSM/GPRS module SIM800L

Tags: power-supply, dc, antenna, gsm, gprs

I have a problem with an SIM800L module. I tried to connect the SIM800L to the network, but it does not connect. The LED should flash 3 times per second, but it slowly flashes 9 times, then turns off, then 7 times, then turns off again, and the cycle repeats.

The power source that I use is 4 VDC, 2A. I connected a capacitor to the power pins.

[image]

GND and NET are short-circuited, is this normal? I tried to unsolder an external antenna connector and cut the wire, but it did not help.

[image]

[image]

I got a new module, but the problem remains. Could the party be defective?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Everything worked, I read the forum about the same problem, but I did not think that this could be.
In another chat they suggested: The antenna can easily ring to the ground, but it's better not to ring the antenna input of the chip

Comment: you should never have an antenna shorted to ground

Comment: How did you solve the blinking problem?